# Execution failed for task path_provider:parseDebugLibraryResources

Tags: flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':path_provider:parseDebugLibraryResources'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider:androidApis'.
  >   Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}
  >   Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\Jay Prajapati\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar.
  >   Cannot parse result path string:
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you find a solution?